# Google calendar api - Set calendar to public?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I can successfully add a calendar, but unfortunately I can't embed that calendar on remote pages like I want to, because it's not set to public!

I can't find any references to setting the calendar's sharing settings/permissions to public.

EDIT:
Found some more info:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert

Seems like this is what I need, I'll report back with exactly how to do this..

Comment: If you find the solution on your own, add it as an answer (do not add the solution in the original post, add it below as a regular answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out: just had to set the "ACL" for default viewer (public) to reader.

I'm getting good at this!

```
$rule = new AclRule();
$scope = new AclRuleScope();

$scope->setType("default");
$scope->setValue("");
$rule->setScope($scope);
$rule->setRole("reader");

$createdRule = $service->acl->insert($createdCalendar->id, $rule);
```

Comment: blast from the past, you are welcome -- 8 years later!

Comment: haha, I read your site with the Diablo 2 map hack.  That's pretty cool.  I was also addicted to Diablo 2 when it came out my sophomore year of university -- 6-7 hours a day and I'd never get tired of that game!

Comment: @ravioli awesome :) I love that game so much, I really really really want to start a Twitch channel + Patreon just writing bots for it and such... would you be interested in that ever?! Trying to gauge interest, that would be a fun few months!

Comment: That sounds really cool.  I hate to say it, but I'm not much of a gamer anymore.  But I'd love to check out your channel when you have it up and running!